# how actually tcp protocol works?

Tags: tcp, protocols, telecommunication

So i started to learn tcp/ip protocol stack. But in all sources tcp protocol is described too blurry. The main think i want to know how actually tcp protocol programly implemented. how  applyed protocols communicate with tcp protocol. what is interface of this communication. For now i think that applied protocols are implemented directly in applied program: lets say browser implement HTTP protocol and this protocol communicate with centralized implementation of tcp protocol which is implemented in OS. IS it correct i have lack of sources from which i can learn this.please recomend me something to read.

Comment: To know how actually it works, this could be helpful to you: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Computer_Components,_The_Stored_Program_Concept_and_the_Internet/Structure_of_the_Internet/TCP_IP_protocol_stack#Transport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: while your question is leaning towards being broad, I am answering it since I think that it is a good introductory question.

TCP is a layer-4 (or transports layer) protocol. Network applications sit on top of it (and other layer-4 protocols like UDP). Applications can interface with Layer-4 protocols via a socket interface (http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). HTTP is also an application that runs on top of TCP and would be using the socket interface. Besides HTTP, there many other famous applications that run on top of TCP, like Telnet, BGP, etc.

One of the best book to understand basics of TCP and options would be "TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol. 1: The Protocols" by Richard Stevens. It talks about how TCP works and various options. Here is a link: [http://www.amazon.com/TCP-Illustrated-Vol-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0201633469](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469)

Once you have read that, you probably should read the RFC itself: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

For details of implementation, you can read its second volume: "TCP/IP Illustrated: The Implementation, Vol. 2". Here is a link: [http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Implementation-Vol/dp/020163354X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163354X) . While this books talks about BSD implementation -- it should still help you understand the basic mechanics of how TCP implementation works.

Comment: Manoj Pandey Thank you very much.